# PHP is not running HTML and CSS

Tags: php, html, css

My PHP code is not running HTML or CSS. I tried this code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
```

, but nothing happends.

This is my first PHP project so I don't know much about it.

If I integrate CSS in PHP, it does not work.

Comment: Define "not running". What happens that shouldn't? What doesn't happen that should?

Comment: PHP doesn’t “run” HTML or CSS. _“but noting happends”_ - what did you _expect_ to happen? Did you check what the generated HTML code your browser received looked like? Did you check what the error console of your browser dev tools has to say?

Comment: Does your file has a .php extension ? Nothing wrong with what you do, i always do it while testing my css to avoid CSS be freezed in the cache of the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Hello) Based on your code, you try to add css file with name: index.css?v=1234567 for example. I think you dont have file with this name, because function time() refresh every second. You can use F12 button to open develop instrumental in chrome and go to console tab and there you will see which files doesn`t loaded

Comment: you can add any ?x= (GET) to any uri, it will work even if you do not treat that $_GET variable . In this case it is meant tp reload the css file each time you call the page ($_GET is different, so a refresh is triggered)